# Yii2 deactivate behavior TimestampBehavior when saving update_at

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-model

I am programming a ConsoleController command for edit some values in some Databases.
The problem is when I try to save the Model.

```
//console/controllers/ConsoleController.php

 public function actionChangeCourseTitle()
    {


      $model = Course::find->where([ 'id' => $id])->all();
      $model->title = "new title";
      $model->detachBehaviors(); //for deactivate the TimestampBehavior
      $model->save();

     }
```

I want to deactivate the automatic save of the timestamp in the field "update_at", with the $model->detachBehaviors() as explained in the yii2 documentation (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-behaviors#detaching-behaviors). But does not works.

Do you have any idea why does not works? am I defining wrong the detachBehaviors()?

Best Regards,

Paul

Update: it was edited in the SQL Definition of the table.

CREATE TABLE `course` (
...

`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

...
)

I solve the problem with ALTER COLUMN as SQL Query...

ALTER TABLE `course`
MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

and I could edit the fields without updating automaticly the field "update_at".

Comment: You can try named behavior to detach single. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-behaviors#attaching-behaviors

Comment: With $model->detachBehavior('TimestampBehavior') doesn't works also. :-(

Comment: `$model = Course::find([ 'id' => $id])->all();` would be array. are you sure this code is correct? `$model = Course::find([ 'id' => $id])->one(); should work.`

Comment: of course ```$model = Course::find([ 'id' => $id])->all();``` were wrong --> ```$model = Course::find->where([ 'id' => $id])->all();``` is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: it was edited in the SQL Definition of the table.

CREATE TABLE course ( ...

updated_at datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

... )

I solve the problem with ALTER COLUMN as SQL Query...

ALTER TABLE course MODIFY COLUMN updated_at datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

and I could edit the fields without updating automaticly the field "update_at".